# Apply autoellipsis early

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a couple of labels, anchored left and right, in a row. I have enabled AutoEllipsis, and it applies, but I want to it to activate earlier - making a bit of space in between the labels. I thought margin would do here, but then the label text stopped activate the ellipsis and it got worse instead.
Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TableLayoutPanel`. Anchor `Label` in columns, and anchhor `TableLayoutPanel` fo `Form`.

Comment: Was kinda hoping to not having to change the layout, but will use this way if there is no other way. Ty!

Comment: If you don't want to change Layout, you will need to calculate and change size by code.